# How to get the actual start time of the service using ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime()

Tags: java, jvm

I have to implement a logic based on the JVM StartTime. How may I get the actual start time of the JVM? Even the JVM restarts internally also can I able to use this ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime() method?

Below is the sample of logs of the service which I run in my environment.

I have started the windows service @ **01/01/2022 10:00:00** by which the code is created using Java. By the time the wrapper service prints the logs like below,

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2022/01/01 10:00:00 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2022/01/01 10:00:00 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2022/01/01 10:00:00 | Wrapper startup method..
```

After some period of time wrapper service prints, the logs like JVM is restarting and the new JVM to be launch,

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2022/01/01 10:58:01 | JVM requested a restart.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2022/01/01 10:58:02 | Going to shutdown the all threads...0
STATUS | wrapper  | 2022/01/01 10:58:09 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2022/01/01 10:58:09 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2022/01/01 10:58:09 | Wrapper startup method..
```

What the doubt is even if the JVM is launching again internally without restarting the service manually will this `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime()` method returns the start time as **01/01/2022 10:00:00**???

Someone help me in this context to find the actual start time of the service.

Comment: Which wrapper service are ou using and how do you start it? Seems like that wrapper service is also a Java based application which starts your application dynamically in its own JVM (i.e. creates new thread, loads your jars inside that thread's classloader etc.). If it forks a new process internally, that should be a new VM so the value from managementfactory should be correct. May be your wrapper has an option to fork process instead of doing the way now.

Comment: Am not sure about this exactly. Am using **tanuki wrapper** to make the jar file execute as a windows service.

Comment: The “jvm 1” and “jvm 2” are very strong hints that these are different JVMs. If “wrapper” also is a JVM, you can try to connect to that JVM via JMX und read its start time. When you’re using JDK 9 or newer, it might be simpler to check the parent process’ start time via the `ProcessHandle` API (it’s very likely that the wrapper is the wrapped JVM’s parent process); `ProcessHandle.current().parent().flatMap(h -> h.info().startInstant()) .ifPresent(time -> System.out.printf("%tD %<tT%n", time.toEpochMilli()));`

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your response. But unfortunately am using JDK 8 for my project.

Comment: When the wrapper restarts a Java application, it brings up a new JVM. `getStartTime()` will return the start time of this new JVM. Generally speaking, this JVM is a separate process that does not have a notion of being part of an external "service". If your business logic depends on the wrapper start time, it's better to pass this start time explicitly to the Java process via a system property. Use [`WRAPPER_TIME_YYYYMMDDHHIISS`](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-envvars.html#pseudo-definitions) variable in `wrapper.conf` to pass the service start time.